# How to write and read delta format with Zeppelin?(Delta Lake installed and imported)

Tags: scala, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, delta-lake

I have installed Delta Lake package(delta-spark) in Zeppelin env and added delta-core dependency to spark - io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0.

Versions are as follows, I suppose I'm using the right delta-core version:
spark: 3.1.1.
scala: 2.12.10

Now, the delta module can be imported successfully. However, once I try to write or read data in delta format, it throws errors. Anyone knows what might go wrong here or how to fix it? Thanks!

For the following code:

```
%spark.pyspark
from delta import *
builder = SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

spark = configure_spark_with_delta_pip(builder).getOrCreate()

data = spark.range(0, 5)
data.write.format("delta").save("hdfs://my-hdfs-namenode-0.my-hdfs-namenode.hdfs-explore.svc.cluster.local/tmp/delta-table-1")
```

It shows error happens in the last line with "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DelayedCommitProtocol":

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o122.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.$anonfun$writeFiles$1(TransactionalWrite.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles(TransactionalWrite.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.TransactionalWrite.writeFiles$(TransactionalWrite.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.OptimisticTransaction.writeFiles(OptimisticTransaction.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.write(WriteIntoDelta.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1(WriteIntoDelta.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(WriteIntoDelta.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.withNewTransaction(DeltaLog.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.commands.WriteIntoDelta.run(WriteIntoDelta.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource.createRelation(DeltaDataSource.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 21) (10.80.3.38 executor 2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DelayedCommitProtocol
    at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:68)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.delta.files.DelayedCommitProtocol
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.findClass(ParentClassLoader.java:35)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.loadClass(ParentClassLoader.java:40)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:109)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main issue here is that your cluster doesn't see the jar file of delta lake. If you added dependency using zeppelin spark interpreter, it has an impact only on Apache Zeppelin. You should upload the jar file of delta lake to `/usr/lib/spark/jars/` in your cluster. The jar file can be downloaded from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/delta/delta-core_2.12/1.0.0/delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar).